# Declaring a local variable in C

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm struggling to understand why I get an error in the following code when trying to compile:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("");
    int i = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

If I comment out the `puts("");`, it will compile.

I'm using [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), and I complie this as C Code, using `/TC`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio C is somewhat dated and uses [C89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288441/variable-declaration-placement-in-c).

For C89, you must declare **all of your variables** at the beginning of a [scope block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474100/where-you-can-and-cannot-declare-new-variables-in-c).

In the case of your code above, this should work

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you could also do the following

```
int main()
{
    puts("");
    {
        int i = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Important note on the second example: `i` is only valid within `{}`. Secondly MSVS does mostly "use" C89, however that's not entirely true. It does support some of the C99 features, however `statement before declaration` isn't one of them.

Comment: Thx for the quick response and a great answer. Out of curiosity; do you know if it is possible to change the compiler in the visual studio?

Comment: @RezaAyadipanah, yes, you can do a "Makefile project" and set up the compiler within the makefile to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using older C standard C89.

C89 standard doesn't allow to declare variables after some function call. All the variable declaration should be at the start of the **scope block** (*Thanks, Gearoid Murphy*).