# Declare variable in if statement (ANSI C)

Tags: c, if-statement, variables, declare, ansi-c

Is there any way to declare variable in ***if statement*** (using ***ANSI C*** only) ?

**Example:**

```
if(int variable = some_function())
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: No.

That is not allowed in C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474100/where-you-can-and-cannot-declare-new-variables-in-c

Comment: According to the [ANSI C Grammar](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html#expression), the grammar for the if statement is `IF '(' expression ')' statement`.  `expression` cannot resolve to `declaration`, so there is no way to put a declaration in an if statement like in your example.

Comment: Declare a variable strictly using a classic declaration of format `type var = value`? No.

Comment: @RandomDavis That grammar is not up to date (but that particular production hasn't changed). Note that `IF` in that grammar refers to the `if` keyword (`IF` is an ordinary identifier). The grammar in the ISO C standard is **`if`** **`(`** *expression* **`)`** *statement* or **`if`** **`(`** *expression* **`)`** *statement* **`else`** *statement*

Comment: I never used to appreciate the value of this construct until I realized how repetitive code gets when you are checking an error flag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you cannot do that.

What you can do is create a [compound statement](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.2) (*anonymous* or *hanging* block) just for the `if`

```
    {
        int variable;
        variable = some_function();
        if (variable) return 1;
    }
    /* variable is out of scope here */
```

Note that for this simple case you can call the function as the condition of the `if` (no need for an extra variable)

```
if (some_function()) return 1;
```

Comment: If you mean anonymous braces, I'm happy about that. I think they're underrated and are a great first step for refactoring.

Comment: The Standard calls them "compound statements" ([C11 6.8.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.2))

Answer (score 2):

From [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html):

> A compound statement enclosed in parentheses may appear as an expression in GNU C. This allows you to use loops, switches, and local variables within an expression.
> Recall that a compound statement is a sequence of statements surrounded by braces; in this construct, parentheses go around the braces. For example:
>
> ```
> ({ int y = foo (); int z;
>    if (y > 0) z = y;
>    else z = - y;
>    z; })
> ```
>
> is a valid (though slightly more complex than necessary) expression for the absolute value of `foo ()`.
>
> **The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct.** (If you use some other kind of statement last within the braces, the construct has type `void`, and thus effectively no value.)...

Simplified examples:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    if (({int a = 1; a;}))
        printf("Hello World: TRUE");
    else
        printf("Hello World: FALSE");

    return 0;
}

// output:
// Hello World: TRUE

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if (({int a = 0; a;}))
        printf("Hello World: TRUE");
    else
        printf("Hello World: FALSE");

    return 0;
}
// output:
// Hello World: FALSE
```

Does anyone really use it this way? Yes! As far as I know, Linux kernel simplifies code by means of this extension.

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only */
#define __get_user(x, ptr)                      \
({                                  \
    int __gu_err = 0;                       \
    __get_user_error((x), (ptr), __gu_err);             \
    __gu_err;                           \
})

#define unsafe_op_wrap(op, err) do { if (unlikely(op)) goto err; } while (0)
#define unsafe_get_user(x,p,e) unsafe_op_wrap(__get_user(x,p),e)
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/uaccess.h#L365

Comment: Interesting, though presumably you can't access the variable declared in the test expression from the 'then' statement.