# C - Variable Declaration in If Condition Available in Else?

Tags: c, if-statement, variables, declaration

If I declare a variable in an if condition in C, is that variable also available to the else branch? 
For example:

```
if((int x = 0)){
  foo();
} else{
  x++;
  bar(x);
}
```

Couldn't find the answer, at least not the way that I worded it. Please help.

Comment: Maybe consider doing an experiment, and post an answer to your own question?

Comment: Experiment result: one can't declare variables in `if` conditions. Won't compile

Comment: @rsjaffe it doesn't appear to be a duplicate; the one you cited is about variables declared in `if` block, but this one is about those in `if` conditions.

Comment: No in C. Yes in C++, see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) for example.

Comment: @rsjaffe Not a duplicate, the other question is about variables declared *inside* `if` statements in *C++*. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Declarations in `if` conditions in C++ only became legal in C++17.

Comment: @user12986714 an answer referring to the Standard would be much better, since the results of experiments might only reveal some peculiarity of a particular compiler

Comment: reopened - the question is about C but the "duplicate" was C++-only

Comment: @M.M yes, standard should always be better than mere experiments. However where can I find those standards? ISO wants to charge me quite a few dollars to get a copy :-(

Comment: @user12986714 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare a variable like this

```
 if((int a = 0))
```

The compiler does not allow the code to run and you get an error

and if you try this

```
if(something_that_is_false){
        int a = 12;
    }
    else{
        do_something;
    }
```

again error because they are on the same level and they do not have access to their local variables.

Warning: you can use this code and runs without error

```
int a;
    if(a=0){
         printf("True");
    }
    else{
        printf("False");
    }
```

and you will see 'False' in screen because It's like writing

```
if(0) // and its false!
```

and for the last

```
int a;
    if(a=0){
         printf("True");
    }
    else{
        printf("False");
    }
```

you will see 'True' in screen because It's like writing

if(5) // any number other than zero is true!

Answer (score 4):

You can't declare a variable in an if condition in C...

> [Declare variable in if statement (ANSI C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643349/declare-variable-in-if-statement-ansi-c)

If you declare inside the if scope, for example:

```
if(something){
  int x = 0;
} else{
  x++; // will cause a compilation error
  bar(x);
}
```

x in 'else' is undeclared because in C a local variable can only be used by statements contained within the code block where they are declared.

Comment: I did not know that, what about C++?

Comment: @aYogii experiment result: no you can't, either

Comment: Since you say this show me the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment result: one can't declare variables in `if` conditions. Won't compile.