# Won't let me declare a string in an if statement C

Tags: c

I'm trying to set a string to be different things depending on an int, but when I declare a string in any if statement, even an always true one it seems to give me error: 'correctColor' undeclared (first use in this function).

If I have this line by itself, my code works fine.

```
    char correctColor[] = "red";
```

But if I have something like

```
bool test = true;
if(test){
char correctColor[] = "red";
}
```

it gives me the error above. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wgiBlS9YCSHm4yDV).

Comment: You should define the vars in the start of the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474100/where-you-can-and-cannot-declare-new-variables-in-c

Comment: It will give warning (unused variable) not compile time error(in gcc). Can you post the full code snippet?

Comment: Do you intend to write to the string later?

Comment: It seems that you have a local vs global variable problem.  Can you post a minimum viable example of something that you're trying, but not working?  Ie, all the code, including where you declare the variable, and where you try and set it.

Answer (score 4):

Please see the comments below

```
   bool test = true;
   if(test){
     char correctColor[] = "red";
     // correctColor is available here until the end brace
   }

   // correctColor is not available here - it is now out of scope
```

Consider if `test` is `false` - Then `correctColor` would not be declared!