# Bubble-sort program returns random numbers

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I'm learning C and my bubble sort code returns a random number sometimes (although sometimes it does returns the correct array numbers).

For example, it should print {0, 1, 3, 10}. But sometimes prints things like {-487420160, 0, 1, 3} or {-1484260208, 0, 1, 3} (only the first number changes, the other are correct).

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

//array and variables
int arr[] = {1, 3, 0, 10};
int len = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(int);
int j = 0;
int i = 0;

//print original array
printf("ORIGINAL ARRAY: \n");
printf("{");
for (int x = 0; x < len; x ++){
    printf("%d", arr[x]);
    if (x < len-1){
        printf(", ");
    }
}
printf("}\n");

//sorting
for ( i = 0;i < len; i++){
    for (j = 0 ;j < len; j ++){
        if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
            int temporal = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = temporal;
        }
    }
}

//print sorted array
printf("BUBBLE-SORTED ARRAY: \n");
printf("{");
for (int y = 0; y < len; y ++){
    printf("%d", arr[y]);
    if (y < len-1){
        printf(", ");
    }
}
printf("}\n");

return 0;
}
```

Do anybody know why or can help me improve the code?

Comment: Hint: if `j` is `len-1`, what is `arr[j+1]` referencing?

Comment: You could improve the code by printffing out all array indices as they are used, eg. by using more temp vars like 'thisIndex=j+1;'.  This is primitive debugging, but would have shown up your out-of-bounds accesses as hinted at by dbush.  Better - learn how to use an actual debugger to step and inspect.  If you cannot debug, you cannot program computers.

Comment: Change your `i` loop to `for (i=len; i-- > 0;)`, and your `j` loop to `for (j=0; j < i; ++j)` . the rest of the code can remain as is. If you single step through the execution in a debugger it will become evidently clear why that works, if you don't already understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of the `for(j=0:j<len;j++)` change to `for(j=0:j<len-1;j++)`:

```
for ( i = 0;i < len; i++){
    for (j = 0 ;j < len; j ++){// here instead of len use len-1
        if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
            int temporal = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = temporal;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in bubble sort we usually compare until the end, but in your case when `j=len` then `j+1` is a random number which has no existence and there is no element.

Make the following change and you will get the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

//array and variables
int arr[] = {1, 3, 0, 10};
int len = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(int);
int j = 0;
int i = 0;
int x=0;
int y=0;

//print original array
printf("ORIGINAL ARRAY: \n");
printf("{");
for (x = 0; x < len; x ++){
    printf("%d", arr[x]);
    if (x < len-1){
    printf(", ");
    }
}
printf("}\n");

//sorting
for ( i = 0;i < len; i++){
    for (j = 0 ;j < len-1; j++){// Here is the change, len has been changed to len-1
    if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
        int temporal = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        arr[j+1] = temporal;
    }
    }
}

//print sorted array
printf("BUBBLE-SORTED ARRAY: \n");
printf("{");
for (y = 0; y < len; y ++){
    printf("%d", arr[y]);
    if (y < len-1){
        printf(", ");
    }
}
printf("}\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474100/

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. I've removed _Also in C I would like you to declare all variables at one place, as C doesn't like to have a variable declared in between program execution._ from your answer. This is factually wrong, see the post linked by SparKot above: in C, you can declare variables pretty much anywhere a statement can go. Also, it's good practice to declare variables in the scope they are used in (for instance, `for (int i = 0....)` is better than `int i; for (i = 0...)`).